# Where-Object match not finding row on partial match

Tags: powershell, match

The following code is not matching on a partial right side match (ie. matching 483 to 483yy):

```
$sdkNum -match '^(\d{3})' #first 3 digits of sdknum
$sdkNum_tmp = $Matches[1] 
$deviceErrDescRow = $deviceErrDescMap | Where-Object {($sdkNum_tmp -Match $_.'Status Code')}
```

For example, $sdkNum = 48312

Then $sdkNum_tmp = 483 #this is fine

My $deviceErrDescMap has a row like this (among many):

```
Status Message    Status Code    Detailed Message
General message   483yy          There is something specific to fix
```

If $sdkNum is exactly matching Status Code, it finds the row fine.  But on matching $sdkNum_tmp to 483yy, it is not finding that.  I have some that match exactly that I am using a similar line of code, which is fine, but if it is not finding the row, returning $null, then I am trying to look for the special Status Codes.

This works for equal matches, but I know I want a partial match to work in above line of code.

Equal match line:

```
$deviceErrDescRow = $deviceErrDescMap | Where-Object {($sdkNum -eq $_.'Status Code')}
```

$deviceErrDescMap is filled by reading in an excel spreadsheet with:

```
$importedExcel = Import-Excel -Path $errorCodeListFilePath -StartRow $startRow
```

And $importedExcel becomes $deviceErrDescMap upon return from a function.

I tried searching the internet for this but not a lot comes up.  Playing around with the code, O found that -match is only working for exact matches, but I thought it would work for a partial match.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

This is with PowerShell 5.1 and VSCode.

Comment: switch the order: `($sdkNum_tmp -Match $_.'Status Code')` --> `($_.'Status Code' -match $sdkNum_tmp)`

Comment: @Theo - That worked! It's so weird.  For my last issue with this type of thing, I needed to have the order I was using with the -eq and {()}.